# After hashing of how many keys will the probability that any new key hashed collides with an existing one exceed 0.5?

Tags: probability, algorithms

Consider a hash function that distributes keys uniformly. The hash table size is 20.

Here I am getting answer 11 considering the fact that probability will of collision will be 50% more only when we already have 10 entries in the hash table and we are about to map one more entry in the hash table .

Is this approach correct ?

Comment: That's fine, provided you are only looking at the probability of the new key colliding.  If you are looking for the probability of a collision having occurred at some point before now, then you might be looking at the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of collision in each entry will be $\dfrac{1}{20}$

After inserting $k$ values the probability becomes $\dfrac12$

Then we have $\dfrac{1}{20}\times k=\dfrac12$

Therefore, $k=10$

Comment: Not quite -- the probablity at $k=10$ will be _lower_ than $\frac12$ due to the risk that there may be collisions among the first $10$ keys.

Comment: Don't we consider here the probability of collision among the first 10 keys ?

Comment: Question is similar to birthday problem and this answer should not be the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first analyze the question a bit:

"After hashing of *how many keys* will the probability that *any new key hashed* collides with an existing one exceed $0.5$ ? "

I feel the question can be interpreted in two ways.

---

> **FIRST**
>
> After hashing of how many keys will the probability that any new key hashed *NEXT* collides with an existing one exceed $0.5$?
>
> or
>
> Find such $k$ for which after hashing $k$ keys the probability that *just* the next $(k+1)^{th}$ key (*any new key hashed*) collides any of the $k$ keys inserted till now exceed $0.5$ (without considering the chances of any collision which might have occurred while inserting the first $k$ keys)

The approach for this is as follows.

Since there are $m=20$ slots in the hash table and there are $k$ slots already occupied in the table. So a collision shall occur for the $(k+1)^{th}$ key if it hashes into any of these $k$ slots.

The probability that this occurs is $\frac{k}{m}$. Now this value should be greater than $0.5$. So we have,

$$ \frac{k}{m} > 0.5 $$

$$\implies k> 10 \quad\quad\quad\text{as m=20}$$

Now as $k$ is an integer so , $k$ is at least $11$.

---

> **SECOND**
>
> After hashing of how many keys will the probability that any new key hashed *TILL NOW* collides with an existing one exceed $0.5$?
>
> or
>
> Find $k$ such that after hashing $k$ keys, the probability that all keys hashed till now (a key which is inserted for the first time is a new key and it can be any of the $k$ keys inserted till now) collide, which is the same as ***(1- probability that no two of the first $k$ keys hash to the same slot)***$^{\dagger}$ exceeds $0.5$.

From $\dagger$ we clearly get the essence of the birthday problem.

Now,

probability that no two of the first $k$ keys hash to the same slot ($q$) = $\frac{m}{m}.\frac{m-1}{m}...\frac{m-k+1}{m}$

Now required probability $(p) = 1-q$.

Now,

$$p>0.5$$
$$\implies 1-\frac{m}{m}.\frac{m-1}{m}...\frac{m-k+1}{m} >0.5$$
$$\implies 1.\frac{19}{20}...\frac{20-k+1}{20} < 0.5 \quad\text { as m =20}$$

Let $\lambda(k) =1.\frac{19}{20}...\frac{20-k+1}{20}$

Now $\lambda(5) = 0.5814 \nless 0.5 $

$\lambda(6) = 0.43605 \lt 0.5 $

So $k = 6$